# how do I scale the image in a UIImageView when in "centre" mode? (change frame doesn't work)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

Question - How do I scale the image in a UIImageView when in "centre" mode?  (change frame doesn't work)  I should clarify in that I would like to be able to do this programmatically.

I can scale the UIImageView by changing it's frame to something smaller but on and same center, and this works (I put a border on view to check), however the actual image in the UIImageView doesn't change.   Remember the UIImageView mode has got to be "Centered".

Background: the reason I ask is because I have some images I want to scale between orientation changes, and they need to be centered, however their views can NOT have a "aspect fit" mode as some of the views are being rotated over time using a transformation, and having them auto-scale as orientation changes occur as they rotate won't work well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to set the *contentScaleFactor* (available in iOS 4.0) or the *transform* property:

```
imageView.contentScaleFactor = scale;

imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale);
```

Comment: thanks phix23 - by the way I posted another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726423/how-can-i-get-the-scale-factor-of-a-uiimageview-whos-mode-is-aspectfit.  Not sure if you know the answer.

Comment: thanks phix23 - by the way I posted another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726423/how-can-i-get-the-scale-factor-of-a-uiimageview-whos-mode-is-aspectfit.  Not sure if you know the answer.