# UIStackView miscalculating UIImageView height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` contained inside of a `UICollectionViewCell` to represent a post on a social network (similar style to Instagram's cells). The `UIStackView` contains an author header (custom `UIView`), a `UIImageView` for the content image, a `UILabel` for the post body, and a `UIToolbar` for the actions. The final view looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjwyl.png).

The height of the UICollectionViewCell is being set by setting up a sizing cell, like so:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      NTVFeedBlogCollectionViewCell *cell = [[NTVFeedBlogCollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 0.0f, collectionView.frame.size.width - 20.0f, 900000.0)];

      // ...
      // Configure the cell
      // ...

      [cell setNeedsLayout];
      [cell layoutIfNeeded];
      CGSize size = [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

      return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) - 20.0f, size.height);

}
```

The problem is that the UIImageView appears to be increasing the size of the UICollectionViewCell, *without* increasing the size of the image view. [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz2dx.jpg) when I add a large image to the image view. The desired result is for the image to remain a 1:1 aspect ratio, constrained to the width of the UIStackView.

The size of the gap between the body label and the rest of the content changes depending on which image I use. This leads me to believe that `UIStackView` is somehow taking the image size into consideration for the *sizing* of the cell only, because visually the image view is its correct size. As you saw in the first image posted, the cell lays out perfectly when the image view's image has not been set.

Here is the setup code for the stack view, image view and labels:

```
self.stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
self.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;
self.stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentFill;
self.stackView.spacing = 10.0f;
self.stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
self.stackView.layoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = YES;

[self addSubview:self.stackView];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[stackView]-0-|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{@"stackView": self.stackView}]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[stackView]-0-|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{@"stackView": self.stackView}]];

self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

[self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_image.png"]];

self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.imageView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[self.imageView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

[self.stackView addArrangedSubview:self.imageView];

[self.stackView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imageView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:self.stackView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          multiplier:1.0f
                                                            constant:0.0f]];

self.bodyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.bodyLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[self.bodyLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
self.bodyLabel.font = [UIFont ntv_lightFontWithSize:17.0f];
self.bodyLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

self.bodyLabel.text = @"While the stack view allows you to layout its contents without using Auto Layout directly, you still need to use Auto Layout to position the stack view, itself.";
[self.stackView addArrangedSubview:self.bodyLabel];

self.accessoryView = [[NTVAccessoryView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.accessoryView.viewModel = [NTVAccessoryManagerViewModel_Stubbed new];

[self.stackView addArrangedSubview:self.accessoryView];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is what worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654375/3185183

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We figured it out! As stated in the docs, the `UIStackView` is using the `intrinsicContentSize` of its `arrangedSubviews` to calculate its height.

`UIImageView` is reporting its `intrinsicContentSize` as the whole size of the image (as you would expect). `UIStackView` was ignoring my height constraint and *just* using the `intrinsicContentSize` of the image view.

To fix this, I've created a `UIImageView` subclass which allows for a caller to set the `intrinsicContentSize`. This code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/KiranPanesar/f0dfa5a7c50c1c66d603).

Then, in my `UICollectionViewCell` I am setting the UIImageView subclass' `intrinsicContentSize` once the layout pass has completed:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Constrain the image view's content size to match the stackview's width.
    self.imageView.constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(self.stackView.frame.size.width, self.stackView.frame.size.width);

    [super layoutSubviews];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The other solution, if you don't want to do it programmatically, is to use 2 UIStackViews vertically. The top UIStackView which contains UIImageView, set its height constraint to take up, say 70% of the superview’s height, and let the bottom UIStackView sit right next to top one, so it will take the remaining 30% of height.

By this way no matter how big your image is, it will always take 70% of the height.